# Oauth2 and Spring-Security: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Tags: java, exception, oauth-2.0, spring-social

I am using Oauth2 with spring-security for secure my rest services. i am using latest version of oauth2 and spring-security dependencies. Following is my dependencies:

```
<!-- Spring Security Dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- END of Core Spring and Spring Web Dependencies -->
```

I am using maven multimodule project. so the version of dependencies in declare in parent pom. Following are the versions of depdendencies:

```
<spring-security-oauth2>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2>
<spring.security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
```

My `Spring-security-aouth2.xml` configuration file as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd ">

<!-- Create client details bean for manage client details from database -->
<!-- The JdbcClientDetailsService provide default implementation for fetching 
    the data from oauth_client_details table Other wise we need to create our 
    custom class that Implement ClientDetailsService Interface and override its 
    loadClientByClientId method -->
<bean id="clientDetails"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.JdbcClientDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Configure Authentication manager -->
<bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
</bean>

<!-- This class is the custom implementation of UserDetailSerive Interface 
    that provide by the spring, which we Need to implement and override its method. 
    But for Oauth spring provide us ClientDetailsUserDetailsService, which already 
    implement UserDetailSerive Interface and override its method. -->
<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"></property>
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="oauthDaoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider"> 
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" /> <property name="userDetailsService" 
    ref="clientDetailsUserService" /> </bean> -->

<sec:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<!-- Oauth Token Service Using Database -->
<!-- The JdbcTokenStore class provide the default implementation from access 
    the token from database. If we want to customize the JDBC implementation 
    we need to implement TokenStore interface and overrider its methods -->
<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- This the service class which is used to access the function of JdbcTokenStore 
    class. This is like MVC structure JdbcTokenStore is Dao layer and DefaultTokenServices 
    is service layer -->
<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<!-- A user approval handler that remembers approval decisions by consulting 
    existing tokens -->
<bean id="oAuth2RequestFactory"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>
<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="requestFactory" ref="oAuth2RequestFactory" />
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
</bean>

<!-- Authorization Server Configuration of the server is used to provide 
    implementations of the client details service and token services and to enable 
    or disable certain aspects of the mechanism globally. -->
<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<!-- A Resource Server serves resources that are protected by the OAuth2 
    token. Spring OAuth provides a Spring Security authentication filter that 
    implements this protection. -->
<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    token-services-ref="tokenServices" resource-id="rsourceId" />

<!-- Grants access if only grant (or abstain) votes were received. We can 
    protect REST resource methods with JSR-250 annotations such as @RolesAllowed -->
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250Voter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- If authentication fails and the caller has asked for a specific content 
    type response, this entry point can send one, along with a standard 401 status -->
<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="empirecl-api/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="empirecl-api" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<!-- Allows clients to authenticate using request parameters if included 
    as a security filter. It is recommended by the specification that you permit 
    HTTP basic authentication for clients, and not use this filter at all. -->
<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<sec:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/api/logout" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" method="GET" />
    <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/api/logout" />

    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>
</beans>
```

Following is my `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
                classpath:security-config/spring-security-oauth2.xml
                classpath*:**/applicationContext*.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>empirecl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>empirecl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>    
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When i start the server, the application successfully loaded and there is no exception throw. But when i try to hit the URL using Postman chrome rest client, the follwoing exception will thrown:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [empirecl] in context with path [/empirecl-api] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1033)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Before configure the Oauth2 with my application, the rest service work successfully and there is no exception was thrown, but after configuration, when i am trying to hit the url for access Oauth token, it will thrown an exception. Following my my url:

```
http://localhost:8080/empirecl-api/oauth/token
```

Thanks in advance, I am new in Oauth and Spring-Security. what the exact problem is ?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, need to remove `<init-param>` from `DelegatingFilterProxy`. After that application will run. I think `security-filter` override the `contextAttribute` and `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring` value not found by the container.