# Oauth2 and Spring-Security: Fail on authentication using Oauth2 and spring-security

Tags: exception, spring-security, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

I want to use Oauth2 and Spring-security with rest web service. I am new for this, i am trying to create configuration with the help of some websites. Still, i clearly not understand how and what is the flow for oauth authenticate for rest service. i am using latest dependencies [Click on the link for see my configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926166/oauth2-and-spring-security-java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-webapplicationco). I am using database for store clients information and tokens. when i trying to access the token, using follwoing url with post request and post body:

```
http://localhost:8080/empirecl-api/oauth/token
grant_type=password&username=a@a.com&password=password&client_id=my-client-with-secret&client_secret=ak_secret
```

The basic authentication pop-up box will appear. I am using chrome rest postman client. I have user table in my database where i store, username and password, when i enter those `username` and `password`, the authentication fail, If i use i my `client_id` and `client_secret` as a `username` and `password`, the authentication is fail. When i cancel the pop of basic authentication following `json` is return:

```
{
"error": "unauthorized",
"error_description": "No client with requested id: a@a.com"
}
```

I am unable to figure out what will happen.

When i trying to access following url with get reqquest:

```
http://localhost:8080/empirecl-api/oauth/authorize?grant_type=password&username=a@a.com&password=password
```

The following `error` will return:

```
{
"error": {
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Bad client credentials"
}
}
```

When i check the error in console, of eclipse, the follwoing error is display:

```
AuthorizationEndpoint:436 - Handling ClientRegistrationException error: No client with requested id: null
```

How i resolve this problem and how to use Oauth with my rest api. I also want to secure my all rest url with Oauth.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things wrong here.

1. You are using the wrong endpoint - the request should be to the token endpoint, not the authorization endpoint.
2. It should be a POST request -  you shouldn't be passing the parameters in the URL
3. You are confusing when the user has to authenticate and when the client does - the server was looking for Basic credentials from the client but you were entering the username.

See [the oauth2 spec section on using the resource owner password grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2).

The [client needs to authenticate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3) and, as porterhead points out, you can do this using Basic authentication. The spec does also allow passing of the client id and secret as post parameters, but prefers Basic authentication.

You should probably make sure you understand a bit more about how OAuth2 works, and perhaps expand your question to explain why you want to use it and why you've chosen this particular grant type.

Comment: Hello @Luke i am able to generate token, but still there is problem to secure my resources, that i need to secure. from rest client, that call to resources made successfully, without any authentication. following is config: `<sec:http pattern="/api/**" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" create-session="never" > <sec:anonymous enabled="false" /> <sec:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" method="POST"/> <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/><sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" /></sec:http>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your client username and password as a Base64 encoded Authorization header.

Try using curl. Here is an example:

`curl -v -X POST \

   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \

   -H "Authorization: Basic MzUzYjMwMmM0NDU3NGY1NjUwNDU2ODdlNTM0ZTdkNmE6Mjg2OTI0Njk3ZTYxNWE2NzJhNjQ2YTQ5MzU0NTY0NmM=" \

   'http://localhost:8080/empirecl-api/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=a@a.com&password=password'`

I have a working example described [here](http://porterhead.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/securing-rest-services-with-spring.html)

Comment: hello, @porterhead what is the actual value of `Basic MzUzYjMwMmM0NDU3NGY1NjUwNDU2ODdlNTM0ZTdkNmE6Mjg2OTI0Njk3ZTYxNWE2NzJhNjQ2YTQ5MzU0NTY0NmM=" \` ?

Comment: String toEncode = clientId + ":" + clientSecret  
  
String encodedStr = Base64.encodeToString(toEncode.bytes())

Comment: @lain Porter i am using `my-client-with-secret:123456789` client information and encode into base64, but still there is problem to send the request.